# How to convert python timestamp in mysql database to date in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, timestamp

I've a timestamp field in my database in which data is inserted from python datetime module. I want to convert the timestamp to date and do some filtering. I can do this in python but instead I want to do this in sql query itself.

I tried this so far

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('ts'), '%Y %b %e') AS 'date_formatted' from tablename limit 100;
```

This is converting to date but the from_unixtime is messing it to dates in 1969 instead of 2013. 
I need to format python's timestamp in mysql.

Comment: What timestamp value is stored in the database?

Comment: Is `ts` the column name of the timestamp?  If so, why are you putting it in single quotes?  That makes it into a literal string.

Comment: @OllieJones Removing the quote fixed it.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ts` the column name of the timestamp? If so, why are you putting it in single quotes? That makes it into a literal string.

MySQL date functions translate a literal string that isn't a timestamp, silently, into NULL.  A NULL or zero  UNIX timestamp refers to the beginning of the UNIX epoch, which is 1-Jan-1970 at midnight universal time.  That's 19:00 on 31-Dec-1969 New York time.  That is, I believe, where your 1969 stuff is coming from.